# Loading component in Angular2/4

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I'm creating an app in angular 4 and I want to have a loading component so the user can realize that he submit a form and the app is doing something, and that the app is waiting for information from the backend.

I did it in angularjs through having a loader component and sharing the action to hide or show using the $rootScope... But in angular2/4 I don't see how I can do this.

Ideally I need to have a loading component that will be over a form or some section of the page (when the information that belongs to that section is being retrieve) or maybe over the full screen.

Could you please give a clue about how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will want to create a loading service that can store a reference to your loading component. Then inject that loading service in the constructor of other components that need to be able to toggle that loading component.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingComponent } from './loading.component';

@Injectable()
export class LoadingService {
  private instances: {[key: string]: LoadingComponent} = {};

  public registerInstance(name: string, instance: LoadingComponent) {  
    this.instances[name] = instance;
  }

  public removeInstance(name: string, instance: LoadingComponent) {
    if (this.instances[name] === instance) {
      delete this.instances[name];
    }
  }

  public hide(name: string) {
    this.instances[name].hide();
  }

  public show(name: string) {
    this.instances[name].show();
  }
}
```

**Be sure to register your `LoadingService` in your Module's `providers` array!**

Then in the `LoadingComponent` you can inject the `LoadingService`, so that the `LoadingComponent` can register itself with the `LoadingService` it should register itself with that service:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingService } from './loading.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'yourapp-loading',
  templateUrl: './loading.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loading.component.scss']
})
export class LoadingComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() name: string;
  private isVisible = false;

  constructor(private service: LoadingService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.name) {
      this.service.registerInstance(this.name, this);
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.name) {
      this.service.removeInstance(this.name, this);
    }
  }

  /* ... code to show/hide this component */
}
```

Comment: Seems this is what I'm looking for... Can you please elaborate a bit more the part of "service that can store a reference to your loading component" It's not clear for me how to do this

Comment: What is the purpose of having `LoadingComponent` registered it self?

Comment: How is `LoadingComponent` going to be used in other components that need to be able to toggle that loading component

Comment: Loading component can be used multiple times, with different names.  When you want to show one in a different component, you inject LoadingService and do this.loadingService.show('name')

Comment: So if I've got this right, say in a `ParentComponent` 's html template, we would have `<yourapp-loading [name]='name'></yourapp-loading>`, wouldn't this mean you would have to user `<yourapp-loading [name]='name'>` everytime you need the loading component? Does this solve OP issue? not according to his comment on @bhavik-patel 's answer, where he implied he wanted to use it only once.

Comment: In our app (which has since been converted to another framework) we had a global loader called 'main' which was in the main app component. We used this one most of the time.  In some cases we had specific additional loaders, with unique names, which would be called in MyParentComponent, and usually had a name like 'my-parent-loader' that might only cover just that component.  Bear in mind this whole thing is just one idea on a way to have loaders accessible to be shown/hidden from inside other components.  There are presumably many ways of accomplishing this

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can have a `loader` component with the `loader` as HTML and you can set the value from the master `component`. Something like below, I have used `material2` as an example.

Your spinner.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loader',
  templateUrl: './loader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loader.component.css']
})
export class LoaderComponent{
  @Input() show:boolean;
}
```

HTML :

```
 <div *ngIf="show">
      <md-spinner></md-spinner>
    </div>
```

Component where you would like to use your `spinner`.

```
<app-loader [show]="showLoader">

  </app-loader>
```

And in your TS just set the value of `showLoader` to true/false.

P.S - make sure you take care of its `position` and `z-index` so that it comes on top of everything.

Comment: Yeah, but in that solution I need to add the app-loader in every component I want to have a loader... I'm looking for some way I can add that just once in a app.component or something like that so I can reuse it without too much effort in each component

Answer (score 0):

This might help you
Create a component called loading component like following with an input class member

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-loader',
templateUrl: './loader.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./loader.component.css']
})
export class LoaderComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() loading: boolean = false;
constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
}

}
```

and in the template

```html
<div class="ui " *ngIf="loading">
  <div class="ui active dimmer">
    <div class="ui large text loader">Loading</div>
  </div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

In the above code i am using semantic-ui frameworks's loader.You can use any loader based on your project requirement.Next in the component where you have to use the loader,in the template just use the loader component as child component like this

```html
<div class="center">
  <app-loader [loading]="loading"></app-loader>
</div>
```

and in the .ts file declare the input varaiable as

```
loading: boolean = false;
```

When you have to launch the loader ,just make

```
this.loading=true
```

and your loader will be up.To dismiss loading just make

```
this.loading=false;
```

This should do the trick.Its been explained beautifully in [here](https://medium.com/beautiful-angular/show-loader-on-every-request-in-angular-2-9a0fca86afef)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, I though that... but my idea is to not be using <app-loader [loading]="loading"></app-loader> in every component> Is there a way I can defined that only once in the site, and then from child components enable or disable it?

Comment: Depends on whethet your loader can be programatically brought up without using html.Which loader are you using ?